# Add-remove folders of left-side of "Save As", Notepad++; other applications?

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, user-interface

I'm in Win 7.  In Notepad++, I have the following in my save-as dialog:

[image: Recent Places, Desktop, Libraries, Computer, Network]

I would like to change this list!

I would like to remove: 

  `1. "Recent Places", which doesn't work at all, 
  2. "Desktop", where I don't save files, and 
  3. "Network" (I'm not on a network).`

I would like to add:

  `1. "tpy", where I store my Python projects,
  2. "tj", where I store my Java projects, and
  3. "dl", where I organize my libraries.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that several methods are available for programmers to implement file browsing, so the files on the left are not the same in all programs. Notepad++ and Adobe programs use a less common method.

### Notepad++, Photoshop etc.

Use [Melloware PlacesBar Editor](http://melloware.com/placesbar/). [Download link](http://melloware.biz/download/warez/Placesbar.zip).

- Open "Melloware PlacesBar Editor" (you may need to expand the view).
- Under the Windows tab, activate the "custom" checkbox (right of the five-available custom folders).
- In the associated "User Folder"-labeled field, enter or browse-to a folder location(s).
- Click "Save" in the upper-right-hand corner of the application.
- Test the results in N++'s "Save As" dialog.

[image: MellowWare PlacesBar Editor preview: main screen showing functionality (drop-down select for widgets like My Computer; checkboxs labeled "custom" for %localdisk% locations.]

### Other Programs (the more common case)

These "Save As" locations on the left are populated by the default "Save As" from Windows Explorer. They are easy to customize.

- Open Windows Explorer.
- Removing items: right-click and select "Remove".
- Adding: add folders to Favorites at the top (navigate to a folder then drag and drop it in your favorites); another way, create a Library under "Libraries" where you have Music, Videos etc. Right-click Libraries, choose New Library, enter a name (i.e., "My Code"). Now you can add folders there.

The benefit of doing things this way is that now you will have improved your "Save As" (and "Open") dialog not just for N++, but for the many applications that use it.

Comment: "Remove" does not exist: "Delete" does not work on "Network": "Recent Places" is not present in Windows Explorer.

"Favorites" is not seen in n++, although it is seen in Windows Explorer.  Adding directories to Libraries does not effect the left-side pane shown in the question.

Please improve the answer (i.e., by adding images or videos clearly showing the result, or by checking your method and being sure to word it properly after confirming it.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Sorry. I forgot that my menus look the same in both menu systems, so I thought it was the Explorer system. It's the other one. Corrected the answer. You have to use Melloware or equivalent. Tested it for N++, it works. Again, sorry---I spent time to write a lot of details because I thought I knew, but I had the wrong one.

Comment: Prior to your edits, I verified that the second half of your answer worked.  Thank you.  This is incredibly useful.  It will save me 3-4 minutes a day.  I'll have to add this software to my donations list.  It's great.

Comment: Update: There is a limit to how many locations may be added: five total listings, maximum.  You may decrease the number of listings to zero.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Glad you got it to work! One thing to remember is that most applications do not use this system, but the Windows Explorer places. For instance if you try to save a file from Firefox, the Browse dialog will give you the Explorer places.

Comment: Yeah, I figured, so I wanted to re-include the info (perhaps I should retitle the question?).  What's up with the 'Office' tab?  Also, I'm super interested to know how it works, brother man.

Comment: How it works... I don't know, I think it's up to the programmer to choose one of these systems. Some choose yet a different system! I'm not a fan of the system used by N++ because it's limited and a pain to change. Adobe programs also use it. The "Office tab" in MelloWare? I've never used it but I think it has to do with programs in the Office suite. I'll re-include the info, feel free to edit as you like. :)